# android MVP - can I have multiple presenters for custom views and fragments

Tags: android, architecture, mvp

So I have an a presenter that is already tied to an activity. The book says that one presenter should be tied to one view. But now I am adding a few fragments and lots of custom views. I am considering a fragment to be a view as well.   The custom views will contain a little bit of logic in them. Both the fragments and custom views are contained in my activity of course.

My question is, should I re-use the same presenter in the fragment and custom views or should each view get its own presenter? I realize this is all opinion based but I want the best approach for testing and keeping code clean.

If i do have one presenter for all these fews then then interface the presenter uses will have many callback methods in it.  Meanwhile if i did the opposite and created one presenter for each view it might be easier to read but how would i test it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`View (Activity)` can have multiple `Presenters`. In case of having multiple `CustomViews` for `Activity`, you can have one giant `Presenter` or `Presenter` per each `CustomView`. It depends on this:

1. If all `CustomViews` share same needs, one `Presenter` for all `CustomViews` is enough. Still two options for `Presenter's` scope:

   - `Presenter` has *ActivityScope*. `Activity` uses `Presenter` and gets called from `Presenter`. Then sends commands, data to `CustomViews`
   - `Presenter` has *ViewScope*. Each `CustomView` creates and destroys same `Presenter`

   In case of `CustomViews` not sharing same needs, having one `Presenter` and `ViewInterface`, they will contain methods of all `CustomViews` needs, so each `CustomView` has to implement all declared methods in `ViewInterface`, leave some empty.
2. If `CustomViews` have different needs and method calls to `Presenter`, they should have their own `Presenter`.
3. If `CustomViews` have different needs and also some common needs, they share common need in one `Presenter`, specific needs in their own `Presenters`. *Example* for this: `ActivityOne` has `CustomViewOne` and `CustomViewTwo`. Common `Presenter` for both `CustomViews` can be `FeedPresenter`(considering both CustomViews have Feed List). Then `CustomViewOne` will have `CustomPresenter1` and `CustomViewTwo` will have `CustomPresenter2` for their specific needs.

Comment: "View can have multiple Presenters" can you please justify this with a reference?

Answer (score 4):

Best practice is to create a basepresenter , then create presenter for each view implementing basepresenter

Comment: btw, this was the best approach that i follow now.